# how to disable Input Radio button using css

Tags: magento2, css

I need to disable Input Radio button using css.
Don't want to use `<input type="radio" disabled>`

Comment: In which page you want to disable?

Answer (score 2):

**HTML :**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="disabled-radio" class="disabled-radio" type="radio">
    <label for="disabled-radio">Default Disabled radio</label>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
input.disabled-radio {
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d1vuqzjo/)

Comment: This is Not working.

Comment: Why ? look the JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" disabled>
```

**Css**

```
input[type='radio']:disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```